# Python - Using pandas and enumerate for web crawling

Tags: python, pandas, web-crawler

So I recently found this code segment online, which is in python and uses the enumerate expression in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://myurl.com/mypage/'

for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(url)):
    df.to_csv('myfile_%s.csv' % i)
```

Is there a way to rewrite this so it can go through a list of webpages rather than a single url and put all information from each page's tables into a single .csv file? My main guess is somelike like a for loop.

```
url_base = 'http://myurl.com/mypage/'
count = 1
for i in range(1,5):

    url = '%s%s' %(url_base,count)

    for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(url)):
        df.to_csv('myfile_%s.csv' % i)
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: You have `i` as a variable in both loops; that's allowed, but avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If all your csvs have the same columns you can do this

```
pd.concat([pd.read_html(url) for url in urls], ignore_index=True)
```

If your urls have the same base like the ones in your example, you would do

```
url_base = 'http://myurl.com/mypage/{}'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_html(base.format(i)) for i in range(num)], ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('alldata.csv')
```

Comment: Where would this go within the current code though? Or is it its own segment of code?

Comment: It would replace all of your code. Do you have the actual example are trying  to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import pandas as pd
from concurrent import futures

urls = [your list of urls]

def read_html(url):
    return pd.read_html(url)

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
    fetched_urls = dict((executor.submit(read_html, url), url)
                         for url in urls)

nums = range(1, len(fetched_url)+1)

for future, num in zip(futures.as_completed(fetched_urls), nums):
    if future.result():
        future.result().to_csv('myfile_{}.csv'.format(num), index=False)
    elif future.exception():
        print '{} yielded no results'.format(fetched_urls[future])
    else:
        pass
```